# Angular 7 production build does not load styles and js

Tags: javascript, angular, production, angular7

I have a small project written in Angular 7 and im trying to build the production version out of it.

When i run

```
ng build --prod --aot --service-worker
```

The build will run without errors as seen on screenshot.

[image]

On the other hand, when im trying to load the app in the browser, it will throw errors in console and will not load at all.

[image]

Any ideas what is causing this? The files are in the same directory as the index.html and they do exist.

Comment: It's because the paths to the files are looking relative to the root, which in this case is at the root of your C: drive

Comment: Because you're loading it from file system, you won't get resources loaded with `file://` protocol, deploy your application on real server to see it in action

Comment: For crying out loud: Screenshots of code and errors _suck_.  Google can't index them, I can't copy / paste them, please - put the _actual text_ into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out that if I want to serve this files statically without using some sort of server in front of the page, I have to set build parameter `--base-href ./`and also use relative paths for the assets like images.

So the build command will actually be

```
ng build --prod --aot --service-worker --base-href ./
```

Comment: But is it correct to make this adjustment or it should work with the default base path?

Answer (score 3):

As said you can use `ng build --prod --base-href ./`.

Another option is to configure your **angular.json** file.

You have to add the following line under `angular.json > projects > yourProject > architect > build > configurations > production`:

```
"baseHref": "./"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for running your built code locally

```
npm install http-server
http-server --help
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>
```

`-p` specifies port, `-c-1` disables caching and the last parameter is what directory should be served.

If you are playing with service workers and want to test them, this is [good source of info](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Comment: That's it? Can you offer any additional insight, instruction, usage, etc? This is essentially a _link only_ answer, which is [discouraged on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/178653)

Answer (score 0):

after compile your project for `production` `--prod` the output files after compiling you can't just open it from you browser you have to use `local server` on your machine to do so you can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: My goal was to use aws s3 to serve it as a static page. So you are saying that is not possible to do as well? ( same issue as when serving the application locally)