# Angular 7 prod build i18n files not found

Tags: angular7, ngx-translate, ng-build

I am trying to deploy an Angular 7 app that uses ngx-translate and translated language files in the /dist/assets folder. I specified the correct base href in build. After deployment, I see everything loads, except the languages file which returns an error code 404 (not found).

Ive tried changing the angular.json file a few different ways. I tried changing the TranslateHttpLoader. Nothing seems to be working. I can see the i18n folder with all the language files in the /dist folder. However its not being referenced.

in app.module.ts

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

in angular.json

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
```

But i end up getting this error in the browser:

/assets/i18n/en.json 404 not found

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue like you, I believe that it is related to this command:

```
ng build --prod
```

Try to use this command:

```
ng build --base-href=/deployed_app_name/ --prod
```

For example if your deployed application name is: `stackoverflow`
the command should be like this:

```
ng build --base-href=/stackoverflow/ --prod
```

And here you will have the correct path to your i18n json files

Answer (score 12):

On `Angular 9.0.4` I faced the same issue.

Only when I had a dot slash prefix in the path as `./assets/i18n/` would the issue be resolved:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/');
}
```

Comment: TranslateHttpLoader's default prefix is '/assets/i18n/', making this a required step when using a different baseHref. https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader#usage

Comment: thx bro! I was struggling with that for almost an hour , and if it wasn't for you, I think it would be even days lol

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue like you,
In my case it worked PERFECTLY fine in my local IIS server, but it throws 404 for the live IIS server (i18n/en.json not found 404).

I went round and round, thinking it is a angular i18n path error.
In the end it's boils down to a server problem.

by default IIS server will allows only few file extensions type.
You have to manually add mimeType for json file (From a web config file).

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
</staticContent>
```

I added this to a web config file (If file isn't there you have to create it in website root folder).

ur welcome...

Comment: Helped me too, was using the azure web app, tried every other option. Only this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you imported into the AppModule ?

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I had imported into the AppModule. Just like you have shown in your snippet. Still not working.

Comment: Make sure your assets folder is at this level:

_/src/assets/_

Are you use angular-cli ?

Comment: Yes i am using the Angular-CLI. When i run ng build --prod, the dist folder creates the build with the assets folder at /dist/<project_name>/assets. Am i not supposed to deploy the app structure this way? The app before i build has the assets folder located in /src/assets like you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path I went to solve a similar problem:

1. Check if the files with 404 error were in dist folder correct path, if not, confirm if all assets parameters are ok in angular.json.
2. Verify base-ref parameter as:

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236676/5419823
   - [What's the difference between --base-href and --deploy-url parameters of angular-cli tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular)
3. And look if you have a correct value in i18n parameter of environment.prod.ts (or environment.ts, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but still an issue deploying even Angular 15 to an Azure App Service running IIS.  Referencing any json config file (like those in i18n) **or** a woff/woff2 font will 404 by default. Redirects and refreshes on any child routes will also fail. You should include `web.config` at the root of the Angular project.  The below `web.config` seems to work well for json, woff, woff2, and redirects -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
      </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect_all_requests" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps someone.